# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file doesn't exist

Tags: java

Asking this question with lots of doubt in mind whether it will be treated as a possible duplicate of this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228284/exception-in-thread-awt-eventqueue-0-java-lang-nullpointerexception-error)** or not. But still I am asking it here as I did not find any exact match of my question.

Question is : I cannot access a file, I am using this code inside an `ActionPerformed` event. The code is :

```
private void asfacd_5_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    File file = new File("‪\\\\Server-bifbtbi\\asfa all\\ASFA DVD 2000 UPTO 2014-Q4\\cdrun.exe");
    Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
    try {
        dt.open(file);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(asfa_cd.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The file is in a network location, shared to everyone which I can access easily through a window.
Error Report:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: ‪\Server-bifbtbi\asfa all\ASFA DVD 2000 UPTO 2014-Q4\cdrun.exe doesn't exist.
at java.awt.Desktop.checkFileValidation(Desktop.java:210)
at java.awt.Desktop.open(Desktop.java:270)
at asfa_cd.asfacd_5_btnActionPerformed(asfa_cd.java:271)
at asfa_cd.access$600(asfa_cd.java:18)
at asfa_cd$6.actionPerformed(asfa_cd.java:135)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

P.S : As a novice I have very less idea about all the error codes, many of them out of my bounds.

I would really appreciate any sort of help on this. Thanks for your time!!!

Comment: Unc and network paths aren't file references

Comment: The same code worked for me once. Thats why I was still opting the same code. Othrwise there are lot other options to do I guess. Even there is no problem with sharing, and I copied the same location form `properties > security` tab of the file  @MadProgrammer

Comment: Yep, I've seen things like work on Windows 7 to SMB shares and fail on Windows 8

Comment: Its is miraculous indeed, because when I started developing the application, it worked fine for me. Today I was just adding a new `JButton` in that particular frame, and this is the result. And I guess a new button has nothing to do with this :|

Comment: It could be an upgrade in Java or some other part of the system. We resorted to using [jcifs](https://jcifs.samba.org/) for accessing SMB paths

Comment: It may sound crazy but, is it due to the spaces embedded in the file name. Something to do with the `filestream` reader?

Answer (score 0):

try to change \Server-bifbtbi\ to the server IP adress

Comment: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: ‪\192.168.0.204\asfa all\ASFA DVD 2000 UPTO 2014-Q4\cdrun.exe doesn't exist.`
**ip is correct** i cross checked

Comment: Are you sure that you have the previliege to access the folder / file ?

Comment: Yes, as I have clearly mentioned that I can browse the files from my PC. From the Network>Server_Bifbtbi> file location.;