# Twitter api & GUI

Tags: java, twitter

I am trying to create a GUI that uses twitters API to search for a tweet using a keyword and then display the top hashtags used in tweets. I am getting a **"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException** every time I run the program. I use a hashtag type that I created that holds the text from the hashtag and a count of how many times it has been used. I would really appreciate some help. I have removed the twitter consumer keys and tokens for privacy reasons.

```
package twittersearch;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import static java.lang.Boolean.FALSE; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
import twitter4j.HashtagEntity;

public class TwitterSearch extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

static Panel panel;
static Label label, label1, label2;
static Button button, button1, button2;
static TextField text, text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6, text7, text8, 
text9, text10, text11;
protected ArrayList <Status> returnedTweets = new ArrayList<>();

private static final String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = 
"*************";
private static final String TWITTER_SECRET_KEY = 
"*********************************************";
private static final String TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN = "******************";
private static final String TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 
"********************************";

public ArrayList <hashtag> hashtags = new ArrayList<>();

public TwitterSearch() {
    setTitle("Twitter Search");
    setSize(1250, 400);
    setLocation(10, 200);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    label = new Label("Enter Keyword:");
    add(label);

    text = new TextField(15);
    add(text);

    button = new Button("SUBMIT");
    add(button);
    button.addActionListener(this);

    label1 = new Label("Results:");
    add(label1);

    text1 = new TextField(95);
    text1.setEditable(FALSE);
    add(text1);

    button1 = new Button("SAVE");
    add(button1);
    button1.addActionListener(this);

    label2 = new Label("Top Hashtags:");
    add(label2);

    text2 = new TextField(70) ;
    text2.setText("1: ");
    text2.setEditable(FALSE);
    add(text2);

    text3 = new TextField(70) ;
    text3.setText("2: ");
    text3.setEditable(FALSE);
    add(text3);

    text4 = new TextField(70) ;
    text4.setText("3: ");
    text4.setEditable(FALSE);
    add(text4);

    text5 = new TextField(70) ;
    text5.setText("4: ");
    text5.setEditable(FALSE);
    add(text5);

    text6 = new TextField(70) ;
    text6.setText("5: ");
    text6.setEditable(FALSE);
    add(text6);

    text7 = new TextField(70) ;
    text7.setText("6: ");
    text7.setEditable(FALSE);
    add(text7);

    text8 = new TextField(70) ;
    text8.setText("7: ");
    text8.setEditable(FALSE);
    add(text8);

    text9 = new TextField(70) ;
    text9.setText("8: ");
    text9.setEditable(FALSE);
    add(text9);

    text10 = new TextField(70) ;
    text10.setText("9: ");
    text10.setEditable(FALSE);
    add(text10);

    text11 = new TextField(70) ;
    text11.setText("10: ");
    text11.setEditable(FALSE);
    add(text11);

    button2 = new Button("New Search");
    add(button2);
    button2.addActionListener(this);

    setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    String display = null;
    HashtagEntity[] hashtagInTweet = new HashtagEntity[15];

    if(source == button){   //SUBMIT button action

        try {

            returnedTweets = search(text.getText());
            for(Status theTweet: returnedTweets){
                display += theTweet.getText() + "\t";
            }

            text1.setText(display);

        } catch (TwitterException ex) {
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TwitterSearch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        text.setText("SUBMITTED");
    }
    else if(source == button1){  //SAVE button action
        text1.setText("SAVED");

        for(Status theStatus: returnedTweets){
            if(theStatus.getText().contains("#")){
                hashtagInTweet = theStatus.getHashtagEntities();

            }

            for (HashtagEntity hashtagInTweet1 : hashtagInTweet) {
                hashtag temp = new hashtag(hashtagInTweet1.getText());

                for (hashtag hashtag : hashtags) {
                    if(hashtag.equals(temp)){
                        hashtag.count++;
                    }else{
                        hashtags.add(temp);
                    }
                } 
            }
        }            
        sort();            
        text2.setText(hashtags.get(1).toString());

    }else if(source == button2){    //New Search action
        text.setText("");
        text1.setText("");
        returnedTweets.clear();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TwitterSearch();

}


public ArrayList search(String keyword) throws TwitterException{

    System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");

    ArrayList<Status> returnList = new ArrayList<>();

    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
    .setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY)
    .setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_SECRET_KEY)
    .setOAuthAccessToken(TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN)
    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

    List<Status> statuses;
    statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();

    for(Status status : statuses){
        if(status.getText().contains(keyword)){

            returnList.add(status);


        }
    }

    return returnList;

}


public void sort(){
    int n = hashtags.size();
    hashtag temp;

    for(int i = 1; i <n; i++){
        if(hashtags.get(i - 1).count > hashtags.get(i).count){
            temp = hashtags.get(i-1);
            hashtags.set(i-1, hashtags.get(i));
            hashtags.set(i, temp);
        }

    }

    for(hashtag hashtag: hashtags){
        System.out.println(hashtag.toString());
    }
}

}
```

This is the error I am getting

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at twittersearch.TwitterSearch.actionPerformed(TwitterSearch.java:179)
at java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Button.java:409)
at java.awt.Button.processEvent(Button.java:377)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at 


java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: When you have a moment, could you also please post your null pointer exception stack trace:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228284/exception-in-thread-awt-eventqueue-0-java-lang-nullpointerexception-error

Comment: I added the stack trace